# How to use a avg expression in the WHERE between clause?

Tags: mysql

I want to compare two value with avg rating of user

```
select * from dt_tutor_comments where avg(rating_value) BETWEEN 1 and 2 GROUP by u.id
```

Comment: Please provide a small dataset as an example of what you are talking about.

Comment: actually i want to find out how many menbers has 2 two 4 avgrating in dt_tutor_comment table    select * from dt_tutor_comments where avg(rating_value) BETWEEN 1 and 2 GROUP by u.id

Comment: "data", as in "numbers".

Comment: avg rating of each user i'm saving in other rating table just i want to joining that table with this query and need to calculate who are having from 2 to 4  avgrating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try this instead? Instead of having it in the WHERE clause, use it in HAVING clause.

```
SELECT u.id, AVG(rating_value) avg_rate
FROM dt_tutor_comments u
GROUP by u.id
HAVING AVG(rating_value) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Comment: @jayaprakashk so approve his answer